¿Cómo puedo hacer que la imagen que subo me la tome y me la muestre en el otro componente (point of sale) Angular 15.1
Lo que quiero hacer es que me tome la imagen que subí en customer-modal.component y que me la muestre en point of sale form component, esta imagen se puede actualizar en tiempo real, así que me debería de tomar la última que yo subo, y al momento de dar guardar, que me muestre la última imagen que subí.
Actualmente lo que hace es que me muestra la primera imagen que subí y si vuelvo a subir otra me sigue mostrando la primera hasta que reinicie la pagina, entonces lo que quiero hacer es un método para que me tome directo la último foto y me la muestre en el point of sale, omiti varias cosas por el limite de caracteres
POINT OF SALE FORM:

export class PointOfSaleFormComponent implements OnInit {
    branchSelected: Branch | undefined;
    idConfigurationInterest!: number;
    configurationInterest!: ConfigurationInterest | undefined;
    configurationInterests!: ConfigurationInterest[];
    imgCustomer: string = '';
    customerForm!: FormGroup;



    distributors: Distributor[] = [];
    distributor: Distributor | undefined;

    coupons: Coupon[] = [];
    coupon: Coupon | undefined;

    idCustomer!: number | undefined;
    customers: Customer[] = [];
    customer!: Customer | undefined;
    customerSelectedEmitter: EventEmitter<Customer> = new EventEmitter();

    statementAccount!: StatementAccount | undefined;

    pointOfSaleForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
        branch: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        distributor: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        coupon: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        customer: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        chargeType:  new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        amount:  new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        terms:  new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
        otherCharges: new FormArray([], [Validators.required]),
        purchaseBeneficiaries: new FormArray([], [Validators.required]),
        purchaseAmortizations: new FormArray([], [Validators.required]),
        status: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required])
    });

    chargesTypes: ChargeType[] = [];
    otherCharges: any[] = [];

    amounts: Amount[] = [];
    amount!: Amount | undefined;

    terms: Term[] = [];
    term: Term | undefined;

    interest: any;

    step1Done: boolean = false;
    step2Done: boolean = false;
    step3Done: boolean = false;
    step4Done: boolean = false;
    step5Done: boolean = false;
    step6Done: boolean = false;
    step7Done: boolean = false;

    searchCustomer: boolean = false;
    newCustomer: boolean = true;
    loading: boolean = false;

    amortization: PurchaseAmortization[] = [];

    purchase!: Purchase | undefined;

    noAction: boolean = false;

    lastPurchase!: Purchase | undefined;

    distributorSignature: any[] = [];
    imageIndex: number = 0;
    @ViewChild("imageViewer")
    viewer!: ImageViewerComponent;
    fullscreen: boolean = false;
    totalInterest: number = 0;
    constructor(
        private _distributorUseCase: DistributorUseCase,
        private _bookUseCase: BookUseCase,
        private _alertService: AlertService,
        private _customerUseCase: CustomerUseCase,
        private modal: ModalService,
        private _chargeTypeUseCase: ChargeTypeUseCase,
        private _purchaseUseCase: PurchaseUseCase,
        private _fb: FormBuilder,
        private _statementAccountUseCase: StatementAccountUseCase
    ) {}

    async ngOnInit() {
        if (this.customer?.getCustomerFiles) {
            this.loadCustomerImage(this.customer.getCustomerFiles);
        }
    }

    get otherChargesForm() {
        return this.pointOfSaleForm.get('otherCharges') as FormArray;
    }

    get purchaseBeneficiariesForm() {
        return this.pointOfSaleForm.get('purchaseBeneficiaries') as FormArray;
    }

    get purchaseAmortizationsForm() {
        return this.pointOfSaleForm.get('purchaseAmortizations') as FormArray;
    }

    getStatus(status: number) {
      return Credit.creditStatuses[status];
    }

    getPeriodicity(periodicity: number) {
        let configurationCut = new ConfigurationCut();
        let periodicityName = periodicity ? configurationCut.periodicities[periodicity]: '';
        return periodicityName;
    }

    openModal() {
        this.branchSelected = undefined;
        this.distributor = undefined;
        this.coupon = undefined;
        this.customer = undefined;
        this.step1Done = false;
        this.step2Done = false;
        this.step3Done = false;
        this.step4Done = false;
        this.step5Done = false;
        this.step6Done = false;
        this.step7Done = false;

        this.pointOfSaleForm.reset();

        const _element = document.getElementById('step1') as any;
        setTimeout(() => {
            _element.click();
        }, 100);
    }



    async setCustomer(customer: Customer) {
        if (customer) {
            if (customer.getStatus == Customer.ENABLE) {
                this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValue(customer);
                await this.findCurrentPurchase(customer);
                
                if (customer.getCustomerFiles) {
                    this.loadCustomerImage(customer.getCustomerFiles);
                }
            } else {
                this._alertService.showErrorAlert('El cliente no se encuentra con status válido.', null);
                this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValue(null);
            }
        } else {
            this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValue(null);
        }
    }

    async findCurrentPurchase(customer: Customer) {
        try {
            this.loading = true;
            const found = await this._purchaseUseCase.getPurchases({
                idCustomer: customer?.getIdCustomer,
                statuses: [Purchase.ENABLE, Purchase.PENDING]
            });
            if(found.purchases[0]) {
                this.step3Done = false;
                this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValidators(Validators.required);
                this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.updateValueAndValidity();
                this._alertService.showErrorAlert("El cliente solo puede tener una compra activa.", null);
            } else {
                this.openCustomerModal();
            }
            this.loading = false;

        } catch (err: any) {
            this.loading = false;
            this.step3Done = false;
            this._alertService.showErrorAlert(err, null);
        }
    }

    async openCustomerModal() {
        if(!this.searchCustomer) {
            this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValue(null);
            this.customer = undefined;
            this.lastPurchase = undefined;
        } else {
            const _lastPurchase: any = await this._purchaseUseCase.getLastPurchase(this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.value.idCustomer, {statuses: [Purchase.ENABLE, Purchase.FINALIZED]});
            this.lastPurchase = _lastPurchase;
        }

        const initialState = {
            customer: this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.value,
            distributor: this.pointOfSaleForm.get('distributor')?.value,
            branch: this.branchSelected
        };

        this.modal.open(CustomerModalComponent, {providers:[ {provide: 'typeRecived', useValue: 5}], initialState, id: 'customer', class: 'modal-xl', backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false}).subscribe(async res => {
            if( res ) {
                this.customer = res;
                this.idCustomer = res.getIdCustomer;

                this.step3Done = true;
                this.pointOfSaleForm.get('customer')?.setValue(this.customer);
            }
        });
        await this.getChargesTypes();
    }

    async getChargesTypes() {
        const res = await this._chargeTypeUseCase.getChargesTypes({
            status: ChargeType.ENABLE,
            affectsCreditLine: 1,
            entity: ChargeType.CUSTOMER
        });
        this.chargesTypes = res;
    }

    async getAmountsByChargeType() {
        const _amounts: any[] = [];

        // this.branchSelected?.getConfigurationInterest?.getInterests?.map((i: Interest) => {
        //     if(i.getStatus == Interest.ENABLE) {
        //         if(i.getChargeType?.getIdChargeType == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['chargeType'].value.getIdChargeType) {
        //             _amounts.push(i.getAmount);
        //         }
        //     }
        // });
        this.configurationInterest?.getInterests?.map((i: Interest) => {
            if(i.getStatus == Interest.ENABLE) {
                if(i.getChargeType?.getIdChargeType == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['chargeType'].value.getIdChargeType
                && i.getTerm?.getPeriodicity == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['distributor'].value.getCredit.getConfigurationCut.getPeriodicity) {
                    _amounts.push(i.getAmount);
                }
            }
        });

        const _a = _amounts.filter((value, index, array) => index == array.findIndex(item => item.getIdAmount == value.getIdAmount));
        const a = _a.sort((a,b) => a.getAmount! - b.getAmount!);
        if(a.length) {
            if (this.lastPurchase) {
                const allPurchases = await this._purchaseUseCase.getPurchases({
                    statuses: [Purchase.ENABLE, Purchase.FINALIZED, Purchase.PENDING],
                    idCustomer: this.idCustomer,
                    size: 10,
                    page: 1
                });
                if(allPurchases.purchases.length == 1) {
                    this.amounts = a.filter(a => a.getAmount <= 3500);
                } else if(allPurchases.purchases.length >= 2) {
                    this.amounts = a.filter(a => a.getAmount <= 4000);
                }
                // this.amounts = a.filter(a => a.getAmount == (this.lastPurchase!.getAmount! - 500) || a.getAmount == (this.lastPurchase!.getAmount! + 500) || a.getAmount == this.lastPurchase!.getAmount);
            } else {
                this.amounts = a.filter(a => a.getAmount <= 3000);
                // this.amounts = a.filter((item, index, array) => item.getAmount === array[0].getAmount);;
            }
        } else {
            this.step4Done = false;
            this._alertService.showErrorAlert('No existen montos configurados para esta configuración.', () => {})
        }
        
    }

    async setAmount(amount: Amount) {
        this.terms = [];
        this.term = undefined;
        this.interest = undefined;
        this.otherCharges = [];
        this.pointOfSaleForm.get('terms')?.setValue(null);
        await this.getTermsByChargeType();
    }

    async getTermsByChargeType() {
        const _interest = this.configurationInterest?.getInterests!.filter( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount']?.value?.getIdAmount
        //this.branchSelected?.getConfigurationInterest?.getInterests!.filter( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount']?.value?.getIdAmount
        && i.getChargeType?.getIdChargeType == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['chargeType']?.value?.getIdChargeType && i.getStatus == Interest.ENABLE);

        const _terms: any[] = [];
        _interest?.map(i => {
            _terms.push(i.getTerm)
        });

        this.terms = _terms.filter((value, index, array) => index == array.findIndex(item => item.getIdTerm == value.getIdTerm));
    }

    async setTerm(term: Term) {
        this.otherChargesForm.clear();
        this.pointOfSaleForm.get('terms')?.setValue(term);
        await this.getAmountsByChargeType();
        await this.getOtherCharges();
        await this.setInterest(term?.getIdTerm);
        await this.getAmortization();
    }

    get perPercentage(): number {
        return ChargeType.PERCENTAGE;
    }

    get perMultiplication(): number {
        return ChargeType.MULTIPLICATION;
    }

    createChargeType(chargeType: ChargeType): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            idChargeType: [chargeType.getIdChargeType],
            name: [chargeType.getName],
            status: [chargeType.getStatus],
            amount: [chargeType.getAmount],
            affectsCreditLine: [chargeType.getAffectsCreditLine],
            calculatePerAmount: [chargeType.getCalculatePerAmount],
            typeCalculation: [chargeType.getTypeCalculation],
            amountFrom: [chargeType.getAmountFrom],
            requiresConfirmation: [chargeType.getRequiresConfirmation],
            entity: [chargeType.getEntity],
            requiresBeneficiary: [chargeType.getRequiresBeneficiary],
            requiresPercentage: [chargeType.getRequiresPercentage]
        });
    }

    async getOtherCharges() {
        const _idAmount = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount']?.value?.getIdAmount ? this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount']?.value?.getIdAmount : null;
        const _idTerm = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['terms']?.value?.getIdTerm ? this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['terms']?.value?.getIdTerm : null;

        const interest = this.configurationInterest?.getInterests!.find( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == _idAmount && i.getTerm?.getIdTerm == _idTerm );
        // this.branchSelected?.getConfigurationInterest?.getInterests!.find( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == _idAmount && i.getTerm?.getIdTerm == _idTerm );
        this.otherCharges = interest?.getInterestChargeTypes!;

        this.otherCharges?.forEach((oc:any) => {
            if(oc.getChargeType.getRequiresConfirmation) {
                oc.checked = false;
            } else {
                oc.checked = true;
                this.otherChargesForm.push(this.createChargeType(ChargeTypeFactory.jsonToModel(oc.getChargeType)));
            }
        });
    }

    async setInterest(idTerm: number) {
        const interest = this.configurationInterest?.getInterests!.find( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount'].value.getIdAmount && i.getTerm?.getIdTerm == idTerm );
        //this.branchSelected?.getConfigurationInterest?.getInterests!.find( i => i.getAmount.getIdAmount == this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount'].value.getIdAmount && i.getTerm?.getIdTerm == idTerm );
        this.interest = interest;
    }

    async otherChargesAlert(event: any, chargeType: any) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if(event.target.checked) {
            const res = await this._alertService.confirmAlert('Se agregara el Seguro COVID');
            if(res) {
                chargeType.checked = true;
                this.otherChargesForm.value.push( ChargeTypeFactory.jsonToModel(chargeType.getChargeType));
            } else {
                chargeType.checked = false;
            }
        } else {
            const found = this.otherChargesForm.value.findIndex( (c: any) => c.idChargeType === chargeType!.getChargeType.getIdChargeType);
            this.otherChargesForm.value.splice(found, 1);
            this.otherChargesForm.controls.splice(found, 1);
        }
    }

    async needsBeneficiaries() {
        const _beneficiaries = this.otherCharges?.filter(oc => oc.getChargeType.getRequiresBeneficiary == true && oc.checked == true);
        if(_beneficiaries.length > 0) {
            this.beneficiariesModal();
        } else {
            this.step5Done = true;
            this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.setValidators(null);
            this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.updateValueAndValidity();

            const _element = document.getElementById('step6') as any;
            // await this.getAmortization();
            setTimeout(() => {
                _element.click();
            }, 100);
        }
    }

    createPurchaseBeneficiary(purchaseBeneficiary: PurchaseBeneficiary): FormGroup {
        return this._fb.group({
            idPurchaseBeneficiary: [purchaseBeneficiary.getIdPurchaseBeneficiary],
            beneficiary: [purchaseBeneficiary.getBeneficiary, [Validators.required]],
            chargesTypes: [purchaseBeneficiary.getChargesTypes, [Validators.required]],
            purchase: [purchaseBeneficiary.getPurchase],
            percentage: [purchaseBeneficiary.getPercentage, [Validators.required]]
        });
    }

    beneficiariesModal() {
        const initialState = {
            otherCharges:  ChargeTypeFactory.arrayJsonToModelArray(this.otherChargesForm.value),
            idCustomer: this.idCustomer ? this.idCustomer : 7,
            newBeneficiaries: PurchaseBeneficiaryFactory.arrayJsonToModelArray(this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.value)
        };

        this.modal.open(BeneficiaryListModalComponent, {initialState, id: 'beneficiaries', class: 'modal-xl'}).subscribe(res => {
            if(res) {
                res.map( (pb: any) => {
                    let found = this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.value.find(( i: any) => i.beneficiary.getIdBeneficiary == pb.beneficiary.getIdBeneficiary);

                    if(found) {
                        found.percentage = pb.percentage;
                        found.chargesTypes = pb.chargesTypes;
                    } else {
                        const _pb:PurchaseBeneficiary = PurchaseBeneficiaryFactory.jsonToModel(pb);
                        this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.push(this.createPurchaseBeneficiary(_pb));
                    }
                });

                this.step5Done = true;

                const _element = document.getElementById('step6') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
            }
        });
        // this.getAmortization()
    }

    async getAmortization() {
        this.totalInterest = 0;
        const idChargeType: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['chargeType'].value.getIdChargeType;
        const idAmount: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount'].value.getIdAmount;
        const idTerm: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['terms'].value.getIdTerm;
        const idConfigurationCut: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['distributor'].value.getCredit.getConfigurationCut.getIdConfigurationCut;
        const amount: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount'].value.getAmount;
        const res = await this._purchaseUseCase.calculateAmortization(this.idConfigurationInterest, idChargeType, idAmount, idTerm, idConfigurationCut);

        res.map(a => {
            let _temp: PurchaseAmortizationChargeType[] = [];
            let anotherChargesAmount: number = 0;
            this.totalInterest += a.getInterest!;
            
            this.otherChargesForm.value.map( (ocf: any) => {
                let _purchaseAmortizationChargeType = new PurchaseAmortizationChargeType();
                let _amount = 0;
                _purchaseAmortizationChargeType.setChargeType = ocf;
                if( ocf.typeCalculation == ChargeType.MULTIPLICATION ) {
                    const calculatePer = amount /(ocf.calculatePerAmount);
                    _amount = calculatePer * (ocf.amount!);
                } else if( ocf.typeCalculation == ChargeType.PERCENTAGE ) {
                    _amount = amount * (ocf.amount! / 100);
                } else {
                    _amount = ocf.amount!;
                }
                _purchaseAmortizationChargeType.setAmount = _amount;
                anotherChargesAmount += _amount;

                _temp.push(_purchaseAmortizationChargeType);
            });
            a.setAnotherCharges = anotherChargesAmount;
            a.setPurchaseAmortizationChargeTypes = _temp;
        });
        this.amortization = res;
    }

    async createPurchase() {
        const term: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['terms'].value.getTerms;
        const amount: number = this.pointOfSaleForm.controls['amount'].value.getAmount;
        const purchase = PurchaseFactory.jsonToModel(this.pointOfSaleForm.value);

        purchase.setAmount = amount;
        purchase.setTerms = term;
        purchase.setPurchaseAmortizations = this.amortization;
        purchase.setInterest = this.interest;

        if(amount > this.statementAccount?.getAvailable!) {
            this._alertService.showErrorAlert("El socio no cuenta con crédito disponible.", null);
            return;
        } else {
            try {
                this.loading = true;
                const res = await this._purchaseUseCase.createPurchase(purchase);
                this.purchase = res;
                this._alertService.showSuccessAlert('Bien hecho', 'Compra generada correctamente.', null);
                this.step6Done = false;
                this.step7Done = true;
                const _element = document.getElementById('step8') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
                this.loading = false;
            } catch (err: any) {
                this.loading = false;
                this._alertService.showErrorAlert(err, () => {});
            }
        }
        
    }

    async sendFolio() {
        try {
            await this._purchaseUseCase.sendFolio(this.purchase!);
            this._alertService.showSuccessAlert('Bien hecho', 'Folio reenviado correctamente.', null);
        } catch(err:any) {
            this._alertService.showErrorAlert(err, () => {});
        }
    }

    steps(id: string) {
        let _element: any;
        switch(id) {
            case 'step1':
                _element = document.getElementById('step1') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
            break;
            case 'step3':
                _element = document.getElementById('step3') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
            break;
            case 'step4':
                _element = document.getElementById('step4') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
            break;
            case 'step5':
                _element = document.getElementById('step5') as any;
                setTimeout(() => {
                    _element.click();
                }, 100);
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }

    reload() {
        window.location.reload();
    }

    clear() {
        // this.distributors = [];
        this.distributor = undefined;

        this.coupons = [];
        this.coupon = undefined;

        this.idCustomer = undefined;
        this.customers = [];
        this.customer = undefined;

        this.statementAccount = undefined;


        // this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.setValue();

        this.chargesTypes = [];
        this.otherCharges = [];

        this.amounts = [];
        this.amount = undefined;

        this.terms = [];
        this.term = undefined;

        this.interest = undefined;

        this.step1Done = false;
        this.step2Done = false;
        this.step3Done = false;
        this.step4Done = false;
        this.step5Done = false;
        this.step6Done = false;
        this.step7Done = false;

        this.searchCustomer = false;
        this.newCustomer = true;
        this.loading = false;

        this.amortization = [];

        this.purchase = undefined;

        this.noAction = false;

        this.pointOfSaleForm.reset();
        this.pointOfSaleForm.get('branch')?.setValue(this.branchSelected);
        this.otherChargesForm.reset();
        this.otherChargesForm.clear();
        this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.reset();
        this.purchaseBeneficiariesForm.clear();

        const _element = document.getElementById('step1') as any;
        setTimeout(() => {
            _element.click();
        }, 100);
    }
    get getCustomerFilesForm(): FormArray {
        return this.customerForm.get('customerFiles') as FormArray
    }
    async customerFilesFormEmitter(customerFilesForm: FormArray) {
        this.getCustomerFilesForm.controls = customerFilesForm.controls;
        this.getCustomerFilesForm.setValue(customerFilesForm.value);
        console.log(customerFilesForm);
        console.log(this.getCustomerFilesForm);
    
        // Buscar el archivo de tipo PHOTO en el nuevo valor de customerFilesForm
        const fileOfType2 = customerFilesForm.value.find((file: any) => {
            const idCustomerFileType = file.customerFileType?.idCustomerFileType;
            return idCustomerFileType !== undefined && idCustomerFileType.toString() === CustomerFile.PHOTO.toString();
        });
    
        if (fileOfType2 && fileOfType2.name) {
            try {
                const newImgCustomer = await this._customerUseCase.getUrlFile(fileOfType2.name);
                this.imgCustomer = newImgCustomer;
            } catch (error) {
                this._alertService.showErrorAlert('Error loading image', null);
            }
        }
    }

    async loadCustomerImage(customerFiles: CustomerFile[]) {
        const fileOfType2 = customerFiles.find(file => {
            const idCustomerFileType = file.getCustomerFileType?.getIdCustomerFileType;
            return idCustomerFileType !== undefined && idCustomerFileType.toString() === CustomerFile.PHOTO.toString();
        });
    
        if (fileOfType2 && fileOfType2.getName) {
            try {
                const newImgCustomer = await this._customerUseCase.getUrlFile(fileOfType2.getName);
                this.imgCustomer = newImgCustomer;
            } catch (error) {
                this._alertService.showErrorAlert('Error loading image', null);
            }
        }
    }
}


Sin ver el código se me ocurre que puedes crear un servicio que sea el que se encargue de proveer esa imagen por medio de un observable. Cuando se cambie la imagen se debe llamar al servicio y decirle que publique la nueva imagen para que los componentes suscritos la tomen.

Ya lo solucioné, unicamente lo que hice fue conectar ambos componentes y que se colocara la foto del componente hijo al componente padre
